# Python for loop in enumerate list goes for infinite

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of numbers and I want to run a for-loop through it, but as I update the list, the for loop does not stop and runs infinite time, here is my code:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
for index, item in enumerate(a):
   if item>0:
       a.insert(index,10)
```

What should I do to just update and insert into list "a" and just doing for loop for pre defined list before adding new items?

Comment: you dont modify a list when iterating

Comment: Loop over a copy of the list: `enumerate(a[:])`

Comment: Note that once you insert into the list, all the indexes returned by `enumerate()` will no longer match.

Comment: You're constantly increasing the length of the list,  so it never ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over a copy of this list:

```
for index, item in enumerate(a.copy()):
```

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you are looking for?  (it is not clear..)
The code replaces every positive value with 10

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a1 = [10 if x > 0 else x for x in a]
print(a1)
```

output

```
[0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```